# Is it possible to execute javascript code after the browser has been closed?

Tags: javascript, synchronization, background-process

I'm developing a JavaScript offline capable mobile web app and the data synchronization mechanism has to be executed in background. The idea is that data is synchronized with server every hour even if the app is not active and the browser has been already closed. Is this possible in JavaScript - something like a cronjob which is executed even if the browser is closed? I found this specification but I think that is just a specification and has not been implemented yet: https://github.com/slightlyoff/BackgroundSync/blob/master/explainer.md

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly, there should be some service meant to run for the app to sync the data. No jQuery is meant to manipulate DOM and won't work after browser close